# Conversion between long* and int* when sizeof(long) == sizeof(int)

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, language-lawyer, type-punning

We know in general `sizeof(long) != sizeof(int)`. But which parts of the (C++11) standard disallow aliasing `long*` through `int*`? Is it just by omission in [conv.ptr], the aliasing rules in [basic.lval], or something else?

```
void f()
{
    static_assert(sizeof(int) == sizeof(long), "");
    long x[] = {1, 2};
    int* y = x; // error: invalid conversion from ‘long int*’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is by omission in `[conv.ptr]` and the applicable paragraph is in `[expr.reinterpret.cast]`,

> `7` An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of
>   a different type. When a prvalue v  of  type  "pointer  to  T1"  is 
>   converted  to  the  type  "pointer  to  cv  T2",  the  result  is 
>   `static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv  void*>(v))` if both T1 and T2 are
>   standard-layout types (3.9) and the alignment requirements of T2 are
>   no stricter than those of T1, or if either type is void.  Converting a
>   prvalue of type "pointer to T1" to the type "pointer to T2" (where T1
>   and T2 are object types and where the alignment requirements of T2 are
>   no stricter than those of T1) and back to its original type yields the
>   original pointer value. The result of any other such pointer
>   conversion is unspeciﬁed.

You have to use `reinterpret_cast<int*>(...)`.

---

**EDIT.** There is a concern in the comments that I am making more visible in this edit, that this is not a language-lawyer question but that the intention is to use the pointer. I am not sure how the concern came about, as it is rather obvious that one can simply C-cast without asking, but if there is doubt - the pointer cast to `int*` violates [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) rules.

That is, an undefined behaviour may arise from the fact that you break the compiler's assumption that pointers of different types could never point to the same memory location.

Comment: That causes the compile error, but even if the proper cast is used, it will still be undefined behavior due to violation of the aliasing rules.

Comment: @BenVoigt Nitpick: I read "unspecified" which is implementation defined without mandatory documentation.

Comment: @peter you aren't looking at the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: @BenVoigt That is true. Where would I have to look? A quick search in the the standard didn't seem to yield relevant results.

Comment: @Peter There's an FAQ on SO titled what is the strong aliasing rule, also see the other answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ok, _accessing_ would be UB (which the OP's code didn't do, but then it is kindof pointless, admittedly, and could be optimized away completely).

Comment: @Peter correct, the code snippet doesn't preform the undefined behavior, but the question is pretty suggestive that he plans to dereference the pointer.

Comment: That is a pretty pointer you have there.  It would be a ... shame ... if you where to *use* it.

Answer (score 0):

`long` and `int` are two distinct types, even if they are the same size, so I think the invalid conversion is due to [*basic.lval.10*]

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through
>   a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is
>   undefined:
>
> - the dynamic type of the object,
> - a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type similar (as defined in 4.4) to the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the
>     object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types
>     among its elements or non-static data members (including,
>     recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate or
>     contained union),
> - a type that is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class type of the dynamic type of the object,
> - a char or unsigned char type.

---

As a side note, if [*basic.lval*] did not exist, there would be other issues: same size doesn't mean same representation / range.

There's no guarantee that the value bits in `int` correspond precisely to the value bits in a `long`.

Comment: The representation stuff is a red herring. The optimizer will assume that there is no aliasing.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes you're right. The representation stuff is now a side note. Thank you.